# How ARP works [Specific Case]?

Tags: router, ip, network, arp, dns

After reading about ARP and NAT I'm really confused about putting them to work together.

Let's suppose we have a router A with a **public** IP of IP(A). Plus, 2 devices behind that router B and C, each with its **private** IP; IP(B) and IP(C).

what if one device wants to connect to device B from outside the local network?

- Does it sends ARP request using IP(A)? If so then how the router know if it should answer with the MAC address of B or C?
- If it sends ARP request using IP(B) which is a **private** IP then how the pocket gets to the router at all and not to every router in the world.

Comment: Did you *really* "read about ARP" - or are you fishing for someone else to do your homework, like all of the other ARP questions this week? How does ARP work / what does ARP *do*? (both have been answered more than once on NE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARP resolves an IPv4 address to a hardware (MAC) address *within a local network* (broadcast domain ~ IP subnet).

NAT translates a source or destination IPv4 address to another IPv4 address *between networks* (with different addressing schemes, esp. public vs. private addresses).

Both have nothing in common, except for dealing with IPv4 addresses at large.

> Does it sends ARP request using IP(A)?

No - different networks = no ARP.

ARP for A's IP address is only used by the last-hop gateway *inside the network*.

Answer (score 2):

ARP is a broadcast that does not cross a router. ARP is only used on the local LAN to get the layer-2 address from a layer-3 address. When a host sends a packet, it builds a frame for the packet. If the destination IP address is on the LAN, it addresses the packet with the layer-2 address of the destination. If the destination IP address is on a different network, it addresses the frame with layer-2 address of its configured gateway (router).

NAT is completely different. It is a process that is often run on a router to translate an inside address to an outside address.